# Please explain how this function works with pointer parameters

Tags: c

I have a function which takes pointers to `int` as its parameters, when I first run the code the result is:

`-47    30    30`

I want to know why, after the second pass through, the values are now

`47   -46   -46`

I can't seem to wrap my head around it, please help me understand the flow of the code.

```
 #include  <stdio.h>

 void  mystery(int *, int *, int *);

 int main(void) {
   int p = -47, *q, r = 31;
   q = &r;
   printf("%d %d %d\n", p++, *q, --r); 
   mystery(q, &r, &p);
   printf("%d %d %d\n", p, *q, r); 
   return 0;
 } /* End of main. */

 void mystery (int *x, int *y, int *z) { 
   *x = *y;
   *y = (*z)++;
   *z = 47; 
   return;
 } /* End of mystery */
```

Comment: Since `*q` and `r` are the same variable, using both `*q` and `--r` in the first `printf` is undefined behavior.

Comment: at least you should try to de-obfuscate the code a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your initial print you made call to function

```
    Here p=-47 and *q=r=30  

    mystery(q, &r, &p); // made a call to function same as  mystery(&r, &r, &p);

    initializes *x=30,*y=30 and *z=-47

    //Here x and y are pointing to same reference.These consists address of `r`

    *x = *y;     // this statement makes *q=r=30
    *y = (*z)++; // this statement makes *q=r=-46 , increment -47 by 1 and assign to *y

    *z = 47; //this makes p=47
```

and 
AS @kevin said

`*q` and `r` are the same variable, using both `*q` and `--r` in the
`printf("%d %d %d\n", p++, *q, --r);` is undefined behavior due to changing value in between [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Answer (score 3):

The `mystery` function performs the following actions:

1. Set the integer `x` points to to the value of the integer `y` points to.
2. Set the integer `y` points to to the value of the integer `z` points to and **then** increment the value of the integer `z` points to.
3. Set the integer `z` points to to 47.

Note that, since `mystery` is using post-increment, the incrementing never actually does anything. That is, `y` is assigned **before** incrementing `z`, and after `z` is incremented it is set explicitly to 47.

Now, in `main`:

Note that `q` is a pointer to `r`. This means that when you call `mystery` on `(q, &r, &p)`, it takes the following actions:

1. Set the integer `q` points to to the value of the integer `&r` points to (this does nothing since `q == &r`).
2. Set the integer `&r` points to to the value of the integer `&p` points to and **then** increment the value of the integer `&p` points to.
3. Set the integer `&p` points to to 47.

As for the `printf` functions, as other comments have said since `q == &r` the behavior of `printf("%d %d %d\n", p++, *q, --r);` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's see what happens.

```
int p = -47, *q, r = 31;
q = &r;
```

Now we have the following variables:

- `p` is an `int` and contains `-47`
- `r` is an `int` and contains `31`
- `q` is an `int *` and points to `r`.

Now we do

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", p++, *q, --r);
```

`p++` means that `-47` is printed and the value of `p` is incremented, so we have `-46`.
`*q` means that we use the value where `q` points to, i. e. the value of `r`.
As `r` is pre-decremented and the order of execution of the arguments is not specified, it is not exactly specified what is the result of this call.

But we know that afterwards, `r` has the value `30`.

When calling `mystery()`, the parameter `x` is assigned the argument `q`, `y` gets `&r` and `z` gets `&p`.

What happens here now?

We do

```
*x = *y;
```

and thus set `*q = r`, a NOP operation (as `q` points to `r`).

```
*y = (*z)++;
```

which means we increment `*z` (=`p`), putting the old value to `*y` (=`r`).

So now, `r` is `-46` and `p` is `-45`.

The latter is irrelevant, as now we do

```
*z = 47;
```

which affects `p` again.

So the values after mystery are `p = 47` and `r = -46`. `q` still points to `r`, so

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", p, *q, r);
```

prints `47 -46 -46`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two integer variables on the stack, `p` and `r`. In the `mystery()` function, both `x` and `y` point to the variable `r` and `z` points to the variable `p`. In the line

```
*y = (*z)++;
```

The value of `r` is changed to 46 and in the next line

```
*z = 47;
```

`p` is set to 47.